# Getting ArgumentNullException in designer window of Windows Phone projects.

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xaml

I´m trying to learn how to develop simple applications for windows phone using Visual Studio 2010. I´ve installed the proper sdk, silverlight, the windows phone emulator, and everything needed to get started. The problem is, every time I create a new project, the section where the windows phone designer interface should appear crashes, and shows the next exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: parentContext at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext..ctor(IMetadataContext parentContext)
at MS.Internal.Host.ProjectMetadataContext..ctor(IMetadataContext platformMetadata, AssemblyReferenceProvider referenceProvider)
at MS.Internal.Host.ProjectMetadataContext.FromReferences(AssemblyReferenceProvider referenceProvider)
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.GetMetadataForDesignerContext(DesignerContext designerContext)
at MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
at MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
at MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView()
```

Added to this, I am not able to modify the xaml code since the other section of the interface "freezes".

Any ideas of what is happening here? I´ve tried reinstalling the sdk´s, silverlight, even visual studio 2010 and this exception is still popping up. I´ve even tried creating new projects and the same exception pops up.

Comment: Did you follow this guidance for installation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402529(v=VS.92).aspx I want to be sure you're not using a virtual machine. You may install over an existing Visual Studio 2010 installation btw.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the install. Have you tried a repair/reinstall?

Comment: Just solved it! I just needed to instal the visual studio 2010 service pack, so that the windows phone sdk wroked properly. Thanks anyway for the comments.